# What file formats are supported by Unity and Hololens?

Tags: unity-game-engine

What file formats does Unity and Hololens support ? We assume only FBX and GLTF file formats only?
Are there open source tools to convert to these formats ?

Comment: Form what to what? And yes, if you search for them / implement your own you can convert whatever you want.

Comment: see [Supported Model file formats](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/3D-formats.html)

Answer (score -1):

The ARR service accept FBX and GLTF file formats only.
    Unity supports FBX, GLTF, OBJ and Maya files.

Unfortunately, Microsoft doesn't provide any specific tooling to convert a CAD file to these formats.  However, Microsoft has recommended using programs like PiXYZ ( https://www.pixyz-software.com/studio/ ) to convert from various CAD formats to a tessellated mesh , which Unity or ARR can read in (such as FBX).  Note, the HoloLens itself doesn't care too much about the the format as long as it is a triangulated mesh of polygons. (HoloLens is just a UWP device that uses DirectX).  But, Unity does the heavy lifting of sending the polygon data to DirectX.  You will likely have to optimize/reduce their CAD data since the HoloLens is a mobile device it can't render much more than 100-200k polygons at 60 frames per second.   So, if you need more "complex" representations of the CAD data that's where ARR can help.

Thank you Cameron for providing me/us the info!  Microsoft Developers are the best.

Comment: Tequnically incomplete answer. Unity supports `.fbx, .dae (Collada), .3ds, .dxf, and .obj files.` and directly thirdparty save files of `Autodesk® 3ds Max®, Autodesk® Maya®,  Blender, Modo, Cheetah3D` (see [Supported Model file formats](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/3D-formats.html))